# Как прервать приложение?

Tags: java, android

Как прервать приложение, чтобы оно в списке приложений было остановлено?

Делаю `finish()`, но это совсем не то.

Comment: Чтобы приложение в списке приложений было остановлено.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704782/android-remove-application-from-recent-apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статический метод `System.exit(0);`

Comment: Приложение останавливается, это хорошо, но оно остается в списке недавних приложений, как можно это исправить?

Comment: Тогда воспользуйся ответом по ссылке, которую дал @metalurgus - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704782/android-remove-application-from-recent-apps

Comment: Спасибо тебе и  metalurgus, если он напишет отмечу тоже как ответ, сделал  System.exit(0); и прописал в активности стартовой  android:excludeFromRecents="true", все работает, правда в настройки->приложения->мое приложение, оно видно как работающие, как это можно подправить? все работает, но этот граф факт остался.

Answer (score 1):

В манифест для `activity` добавить атрибут `android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

```
<activity
    android:name=".Your_Root_Activity_Name"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    .... 
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю воспользоваться таким методом:

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
```

добавьте перехват кнопки `HOME` и должно все работать как надо )